# How to turn off item-creation spam in chat

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

Sometimes while playing minecraft I can't deal with the message spam of other people creating items on my server.  Can't see enemies through it, etc etc.  Is there a way to turn off -just- item creation messages 
E.g.

> giving someUser 3 of Dirt

in chat?  The choices for chat settings currently are, unhappily:

- chat: hidden
- chat: shown
- chat: commands only

So every option but the one I need.  Any other workaround?

Comment: Deop the other players so the can't use `/give` :P

Comment: I'm not sure, but deopping yourself might work too.

Answer (score 2):

Although you did not specify, I'm assuming that the items are being spawned using NEI. If that is the case, you will want to edit `config/NEIServer.cfg`, modifying the line

```
notify-item=CONSOLE, OP
```

to

```
notify-item=CONSOLE
```

If your users are using the `/give` command, this won't work but I can't imagine why they would as NEI is far easier to use.

Comment: That sounds very promising, yes, I'll definitely make that happen!

Answer (score 0):

```
/gamerule logadmincommands false
```

This should do it if they are typing in the commands using chat.

If they are using command blocks use the command:

```
/gamerule commandblockoutput false
```